# Class template befriending function template

Tags: c++, templates

I get a linker error when I try to create an executable from the following code. I get the impression I need to place a few "`typename`s" around or make some forward declarations; I've tried a few combinations but none worked.

```
template<typename T>
class enabled
{
  private:
    T type_;
    friend const T& typeof(const enabled<T>& obj); // Offending line
};

template<typename T>
const T& typeof(const enabled<T>& obj) {
    return obj.type_;
}


int main()
{
    enabled<std::string> en;
    std::cout << typeof(en);

    std::cin.clear(), std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::string const& __cdecl typeof(class enabled<class std::string> const&)"

Comment: gcc appears to give a more useful diagnostic [I changed `typeof` to `type` since gcc has a `typeof` extension]: prog.cpp:17: warning: friend declaration ‘const T& type(const enabled<T>&)’ declares a non-template function
prog.cpp:17: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)   Not sure how to turn that into a solution, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By forward declaring and specifying that the function is templated

```
template<typename T> class enabled;

template<typename T>
const T& typeof(const enabled<T>& obj) {
    return obj.type_;
}

template<typename T>
class enabled
{
  private:
    T type_;
    friend const T& typeof<>(const enabled<T>& obj);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the function which is a friend of the class, is not a function template, while the function you actually have defined is a function template.

All that you need to do is make the friend a function template as:

```
template<typename T>
class enabled
{
  private:
    T type_;

    template<typename U> //<-------------------------------note this
    friend const U& typeof_(const enabled<U>& obj);  //use U 
};
```

Now this compiles just fine : http://www.ideone.com/VJnck

But it makes all instantiations of `typeof_<U>` friend of all instantiations of `enabled<T>`, which means `typeof_<int>` is a friend of `enabled<T>` for all possible value of `T`, and vice versa.

So a better solution is to make the function non-template **and** define it inside the class as:

```
template<typename T>
class enabled
{
  private:
    T type_;

    friend const T& typeof_(const enabled<T>& obj)
    {
        return obj.type_;
    }
};
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/Rd7Yk

Note that I replaced `typeof` with `typeof_`, as GCC has an extension with name `typeof`, and so it was giving error on ideone (as I can't turnoff extensions).

Comment: Won't that make the whole template a friend? I want only a specific instance of the template to be a friend.

Comment: Is `typeof` a reserved keyword? I'd rather use `type_of` then, instead of `typeof_`.